# Why is my oven bulb so hard to turn?

Tags: oven, light, bulb

My oven light burned out. When I try to turn the new light bulb in my Kenmore oven it's like sandpaper against sandpaper. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

The socket is probably corroded or has debris in it, using oven cleaner sprays is very hard on that socket because it is not coated with porcelain enamel like the rest of the oven. It is bare metal, usually aluminum. Cleaning it can be tricky but if you endeavor to do it, **unplug the oven first** or **turn off the circuit breaker if the oven is hardwired** and wipe it with a damp (not wet) sponge or cloth and let it dry thoroughly before plugging the oven back in. Then you can spray a spritz of cooking spray on a paper towel and wipe it onto the bulb threads (not the button on the end though) before screwing it in. If it were not an oven you could use a little rub of bar soap on the bulb threads, but that will impart a flavor to your food in this case.

Comment: It is quite likely that the oven is hardwired. I suggest changing "unplug the oven first" should be **unplug the oven or turn off the circuit breaker**

Comment: It is important to note that if you elect to use a cleaning chemical, it must be non conductive, or make sure all of its residue is cleaned off before reinstalling the lamp and activating the circuit. I usually use denatured alcohol.

Comment: @manassehkatz, feel free to make such edits yourself. This is a community-edited network.

Comment: I would suggest that unplugging an oven is a mistake.  It typically requires moving the stove, often messy, insertion/removal forces are extreme while access angles are ungainly, and this socket is not made for frequent plug/unplug.

Answer (score 1):

Carbon can form in a hot electrical environment. Use a PLASTIC vacuum nozzle to suck out the socket. OR use a clean dry toothbrush to clean it out by rotating the toothbrush, and then vacuum out the socket. Wear gloves for protection against shock and broken bulb glass.

Answer (score 0):

If either the socket or bulb base is aluminum , it has probably galled. No nice fix; turn off power and twist, you will likely need to replace both socket and bulb.